# "identical" pages result different in mobile. One page is like desktop mode in active

Tags: css

For as far as I can explain I have 2 identical pages for  concerning the layout.
I'm working for a friend on his website to make it mobile. I started with the landing page which seems to be working so far.
Since he's going on holiday the question was to do the holiday page first
Basically a copy/ modification job . . . . . I thought.
The issue however is that the test of the landing (https://huurfietsdelft.nl/2017/test/test10.html) renders ok in mobile. However the holiday (https://huurfietsdelft.nl/2017/test/testvak.html) page remain in desktop mode while the device is obvious not ticked for that.

Both pages have their specific CSS file, a copy for the general with additional specifics.
I have been going over the code to find the issue that is causing this, but after two day I'm a bit blindfolded I guess. I found a number of css that was not doing anything so I deleted some.

Can somebody have a look and see if they have the same result and if so, where did I forget a carracter that messes up the rendering?

Thanks and for all Americans: Happy 4th of July!
Marc

Comment: The media queries seem to work on both pages?

Comment: @ Gustaf, thanks for letting me know. Could you tell me the device you are looking on. On my PC with scrinking window its works OK. However on my tablet Samsung Galaxy Tab2 (7") it shows different. The testvak is show as desktop for some reason. I can't clarify this.

Comment: After intensive recoding with W3school examples it still did not work so it was not the code itself aparently.
So I looked higher in the coding of the page and there it was:  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=no">
The part of maximum-scale=no was the issue. After removing it all rendered fine.